# Django all-auth: How to get list of facebook friends using the same site?

Tags: django, facebook, facebook-graph-api, django-allauth, django-socialauth

I am using `Django` for my project and `django-allauth` for authentication. When any user logs in using facebook, how can I get the 'list' of his `facebook friends` already signed up on my site so that I can make him/her follow them on my site too?

Or should I use `django-socialauth` to make it easier?

Also how do I `import contacts from Google account` if an user links the account with `Google`?

I am a beginner. Please help!

Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

In your SOCIALACCOUNT_PROVIDERS settings, make sure facebook scope includes 'user_friends' and the fields include 'friends'

```
SOCIALACCOUNT_PROVIDERS = 
{'facebook':
   {'METHOD': 'oauth2',
    'SCOPE': ['email', 'public_profile', 'user_friends'],
    'AUTH_PARAMS': {'auth_type': 'reauthenticate'},
    'FIELDS': [
        'id',
        'email',
        'name',
        'first_name',
        'last_name',
        'friends'],
    'VERSION': 'v2.4'
   }
}
```

> Only friends who installed this app are returned in API v2.0 and
>   higher. total_count in summary represents the total number of friends,
>   including those who haven't installed the app.
>   [Learn More](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog#v2_0)

Using the above will give your a paginated array of friends that have already signed up on your site.

As for Google, I'll need to look into it. I'll update my answer if I find anything that can help you.

Comment: Thanks! I ll try it out and let you know.

Comment: Where will I be getting the paginated array?

Comment: The paginated array is stored in the Social Account model in the Extra Data field. This field is a JSON array, which contains an array for 'friends' which in turn has a array called 'data' which is the one you're looking for. Refer to the facebook graph tool for more details on what the array contains.

Comment: In the Extra data field it is just the name and the id, I think that there are some syntactical changes in your code in the answer above, I corrected them in my site but still I am not getting the required things.

Comment: The extra data field contains everything that is mentioned in the 'FIELDS' in SOCIALACCOUNT_PROVIDERS for facebook, provided the user has given permission to access these things. For things like friends and email, you need to mention the appropriate scope in the settings too.